# Emmet VSCode не существует в настройках, его нету в списке расширений

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Раньше заходя в настройки пользователя, в меню установленных расширений был доступен Emmet и настройки к нему отображались списком, я можно было ставить галочки для удобства. Плагин конечно не работает и не открывает код нажатием Tab . В файле settings.json  прописывал :

```
"files.associations": {"*html": "html"},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
     "html": "html",
     "cshtml": "html",
     "razor": "html"
}
```

Но команды в файле json выделены тусклым цветом и при наведении курсором пишет "Неизвестный параметр конфигурации". Также при попытке нажать Tab в html/css/js документе , внизу справа выскакивает окно abbreviation doesn't work 1[image: скрин] [image: скрин2]

Answer (score 0):

Плагин был в режиме отключен в списке расширений. Ответ найден сам себе))